# Set hard CPU limits in a Docker Swarm

Tags: resources, cpu, limit, docker-swarm

I am trying to set hard CPU and memory limits in a Docker Swarm consisting of three VMs. I am using the cpu and memory limit configurations suggested by [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) in my `docker-compose.yml` file.  My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: user/testing:part2
    deploy:
      replicas: 10
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 4M    
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

The CPU and memory resources of my host machine and the VMs are shown in the figure below. My host machine has `4` CPUs and all the VMs have `1` CPU each.

[image]

To figure out if Docker containers can limit their resources, I am running a test program with an `infinite loop` in my swarm. One of the snapshots from my experiments is shown below. It shows `docker stats` results on the three VMs (VM1: bottom left, VM2: top right, VM3: bottom right).

[image]

Looking at the results, I have a few questions.

1. How is the CPU limited to `50%` for each container?
2. Each VM has `1` CPU then how come on one VM, docker containers CPU%    sum exceeds `100%`?
3. In the image above, I have `7` docker containers running and sum of    CPU% for all of them is `22+21+88+52+66+78+76 = 403` approx. which
   means that    the swarm is using `4` cores instead of `3`. Is it
   possible that    docker allows the swarm to use CPU resources of the
   host machine as    well if needed?

Can anybody please guide me with these questions? Thank you.